# SQL update query to update end date with start date

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have 3 columns

| Manager | Start_Year | End_Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Suresh | 2016 | 2017 |
| Suresh | 2017 | 2018 |
| Alok | 2018 | 2019 |
| Suresh | 2019 | 2020 |

I want output like this:

| Manager | Start_Year | End_Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Suresh | 2016 | 2018 |
| Alok | 2018 | 2019 |
| Suresh | 2019 | 2020 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.